# Unclaim MSDN subscription product key

Tags: license-key, msdn, subscription

MSDN's portal lets you claim product subscription keys. You can claim keys and see what keys have been claimed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/keys/).

I've claimed a Windows 7 key for my laptop a couple of years ago, however due to OS decay I'd like to completely reinstall the laptop. Must I unclaim the key before formatting the hard drive? and if so - how?

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to unclaim it, and it should activate fine. especially since your activation hardware hash will be identical, MS shouldn't have any problem with it. I've used this win7 key (technet) on a number of builds of this box, and its predecessor.

Comment: See [followup question](http://superuser.com/q/616514/41093)