# Moving MSDN product license key between systems

Tags: license-key, msdn

I've claimed an MSDN product license key for Win 7 for my laptop a couple of years ago.

Recently I bought a new laptop and I'd like to use the same product key on the new laptop, mainly because I haven't found a way to unclaim it and then claim a new one. Assuming I won't be using my old laptop anymore, what would happen if I use the same key on the new laptop, which would have a different activation hardware hash than the old one?

Comment: Your link wont work since we cant sign in on your account.  Also, you dont want people seeing that kind of information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unclaim MSDN subscription product key](http://superuser.com/questions/616212/unclaim-msdn-subscription-product-key)

Comment: Please do not ask the same question repeatedly.

Comment: @Keltari - the link had no credentials, anyone with an MSDN account can login, reach this page and see his own product keys. And that's why I placed it.

Comment: @Keltari - it is not a duplicate: in this question I'm asking about moving a key between different systems whereas in the question you've linked to I ask about reinstalling the same machine.

Comment: @Keltari - following my explanations - will you revert your edit, delete your comments and unmark the question as duplicate?

Comment: @Jonathan: Unfortunately we can't undo our votes. Perhaps a mod can do so, but unless 4 more people vote the same way you don't have to worry.